# Delete columns in Excel depending on a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very important question about deleting some columns containing unnecessary data in excell and shift the rest of the columns to left after deletion. I have tried some VBA macro that i have found in a small google search and that macro, the link that i have found that macro was    http://analysistabs.com/vba/delete-columns-with-specific-data-excel-macro-example-code/

The problem is when i have tried to use this macro with the instruction of the writer it is not working and i don't have the knowledge for understanding why it is not working or not. Thats why i want if you guys can give me some advise for dummies version of writing a Macro for **deleting any column** if the column contains in **cell 170 "0"** and **leave the column undeleted** if the column contains and other number **except "0" on cell 170** of the column. i gave an example of my excell documents as a picture below. i want the columns remain with me with green circled and delete the columns that i exampled with red circles.

This Matrix contains **"2000"** columns between column **A and BXX** and **"170"** rows with sample codes in the 1st column and result code in the 1st row. the 170th row contains the total of the column and i want to delete this column if the column sum is "0"

Thanks for your answers..
Best Regards.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solved your problem by clicking on the checkbox on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
Sub ColumnKiller()
    Dim Nrow As Long, Nend As Long, i As Long
    Nrow = 170
    Nend = Cells(Nrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = Nend To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(Nrow, i) <> "" Then
            If Cells(Nrow, i) = 0 Then
                Cells(Nrow, i).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply it has worked for me and you have helped me very much.