# Deleting columns using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using macros for some functioning.
What i am trying to achieve is as follows:

I have 12 toggle buttons for each month, on click of each button if the value is true i am appending these months in a variable separated by ";".( eg: Jan;Feb;Mar )
Now i have a table which has 12 columns for each month, here i want to delete the columns those were not selected in toggle buttons on click of a button.

Can anyone suggest me how i can achieve this ?

Comment: you want to delete it or just toggle off, hiding it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete columns in Excel depending on a specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471650/delete-columns-in-excel-depending-on-a-specific-cell)

Comment: I want to delete them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to delete columns using VBA in Excel:

```
Sheets("Table1").Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: you can use a SelectCase or If condition for this

Comment: Can you explain this as i am new to this?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.